# my is not submitting the data to database I walk through the code every thing is fine can not find the problem I'm using Laravel and tailwinds

Tags: html, laravel, forms, routes, tailwind-css

this is my controller for now I use 2 methods create and store and  I check for the data submission from PHP my admin i watch lots of vides and the documentation but nothing help and i walk through the code tens times but nothing finds please any one to help the problem nothing goes wrong no error appear but still not sumbmitting the form also it does nit redirected me back as i sepecify in store method

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\generalForm;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GeneralFormController extends Controller
{
   
    public function index()
    {
    //
    }

    
    public function create()
    {
     return view('getStarted');
    }

 
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'startup_name' => 'required',
            'first_name' => 'required|string',
            'last_name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'mobile_number' => 'required|numeric|min:10|max:10',
            'Adress' => 'required',
            'Services[]' => 'required',
            'Needs[]' => 'required',
            'project_phase' => 'required',
     ]);

    
        dd($request->all());
        $input= generalForm::create([
            'startup_name' => $request->startup_name,
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'mobile_number' => $request->mobile_number,
            'Address' => $request->Address,
            'Services[]' => implode(",",$request->Services[]),
            'Needs[]' => implode(",",$request->Needs[]),
            'project_phase' => $request->project_phase,

        ]); 

        return redirect()->back();
    }


    public function show(generalForm $generalForm)
    {
        //
    }

  
    public function edit(generalForm $generalForm)
    {
        //
    }

 
    public function update(Request $request, generalForm $generalForm)
    {
        //
    }

  
    public function destroy(generalForm $generalForm)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('general_forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('startup_name');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('mobile_number');
            $table->string('Address');
            $table->string('Services');
            $table->string('Needs');
            $table->string('project_phase');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('general_forms');
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{tailwindcss('css/app.css')}}" />

     <!--Services style-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.4.8/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

     <!--Services script-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.4.8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>

    <title>Get Started</title>
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    @vite('resources/js/script.js')
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav id="Home"class="relative container mx-auto px-6">
      <!-- Flex container -->
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="pt-2">
          <img class= "md:1/2 h-32 w-32" src="img/SniperLogo1.SVG" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>

    
    </nav>
    
<!--
  This component uses @tailwindcss/forms

  yarn add @tailwindcss/forms
  npm install @tailwindcss/forms

  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')]
-->



<!---General info-->

<div class="max-w-screen-xl  px-4 mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8 ">
  <div class="max-w-lg mx-auto">
    <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold text-center text-darkRed sm:text-3xl">Get started today</h1>

    <p class="max-w-md mx-auto mt-4 text-center text-gray-500">
    Every <a class="text-darkRed">Sniper</a> has A story , create yours now
    </p>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/store')}}"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="p-8 mt-6 mb-0 space-y-4 rounded-lg shadow-xl" >
       @csrf

      <div >
        <label for="startup_name" class="text-md font-medium">Startup-SMEs Name</label>
        <div class="relative mt-1">
          <input type="text" id="startup_name" name="startup_name" class="w-full p-4 pr-12 text-sm border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-sm" placeholder="Enter Startup-SMEs Name"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div >
        <label for="first_name" class="text-md font-medium">First Name</label>
        <div class="relative mt-1">
          <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"  class="w-full p-4 pr-12 text-sm border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-sm" placeholder="Enter First Name"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="last_name" class="text-md font-medium">Last Name</label>
        <div class="relative mt-1">
          <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class="w-full p-4 pr-12 text-sm border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-sm" placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <label for="email" class="text-md font-medium">Email</label>
        <div class="relative mt-1">
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="w-full p-4 pr-12 text-sm border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-sm" placeholder="Enter email"/>

          <span class="absolute inset-y-0 inline-flex items-center right-4">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M16 12a4 4 0 10-8 0 4 4 0 008 0zm0 0v1.5a2.5 2.5 0 005 0V12a9 9 0 10-9 9m4.5-1.206a8.959 8.959 0 01-4.5 1.207"/>
            </svg>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="mobile_number" class="text-md font-medium">Phone Number</label>
        <div class="relative mt-1">
          <input type="tel" id="mobile_number" name="mobile_number" class="w-full p-4 pr-12 text-sm border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-sm" placeholder="Enter Phone Number"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="Address" class="text-md font-medium">Address</label>
        <div class="relative mt-1">
          <input type="text" id="Address" name="Address" class="w-full p-4 pr-12 text-sm border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-sm" placeholder="Enter Address"/>
        </div>
      </div>


           <!--- Services --->
    <div class="flex">
      <div>
       <label for="Services" class="text-md font-medium">Services</label>

      <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"  checked name="Services[]" value="MARKETING">
      <label class="text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black" for="Services[]"  >MARKETING
      </label>
      </div>

     <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"  name="Services[]" value="BUSINESS MODEL">
      <label class="text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black" for="Services[]" >BUSINESS MODEL
      </label>
     </div>

     <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox" name="Services[]" value="OPERATION">
      <label class="text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black" for="Services[]" >OPERATION
      </label>
     </div>

     <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"   name="Services[]" value="FRASIIBILITY STUDY" >
      <label class="text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black" for="Services[]" >FRASIIBILITY STUDY
      </label>
     </div>

     <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"  name="Services[]" value="TECHNOLOGY" >
      <label class="text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black" for="Services[]" >TECHNOLOGY
      </label>
     </div>

     <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"  name="Services[]" value="FRANCHISE" >
      <label class="text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black" for="Services[]" >FRANCHISE
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"   name="Services[]" value="FUNDING" >
      <label class="text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black" for="Services[]" >FUNDING
      </label>
     </div>

     <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"   name="Services[]" value="Offices" >
      <label class="text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black" for="Services[]" >Offices
      </label>
     </div>

    </div>

  </div>


     <!--- NEEDS --->
   <div class="flex">
    <div>
     <label for="Needs" class="text-md font-medium">Needs</label>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"  checked name="Needs[]" value="Consultation">
        <label class="form-check-label inline-block text-gray-800" for="Needs[]"  >Consultation
        </label>
     </div>

      <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"   name="Needs[]" value="Mentorship">
      <label class="form-check-label inline-block text-gray-800" for="Needs[]">Mentorship
      </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"  name="Needs[]" value="Knowledge">
      <label class="form-check-label inline-block text-gray-800" for="Needs[]" >Knowledge
      </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input appearance-none h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white  mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2  text-darkRed" type="checkbox"   name="Needs[]" value="Incubation"  >
      <label class="form-check-label inline-block text-gray-800" for="Needs[]" >Incubation
      </label>
      </div>
 
    </div>

   </div>



     <!--- Your project phase  --->

      <div>
        <label for="Address" class="text-md font-medium">Your project phase</label>
        <div class="relative mt-1">

        <div class="flex items-center mb-2">
        <input checked id="project_phase" type="radio" value="IDEA" name="project_phase" class="w-4 h-4 text-darkRed border-gray-300 bg-white">
    <label for="project_phase" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black">IDEA</label>
    </div>

  <div class="flex items-center mb-2">
    <input  id="project_phase" type="radio" value="FEASIBILITY STUDY" name="project_phase" class="w-4 h-4 text-darkRed border-gray-300 bg-white">
    <label for="project_phase" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black">FEASIBILITY STUDY</label>
   </div>

  <div class="flex items-center mb-2">
  <input id="project_phase" type="radio" value="PRESEED" name="project_phase" class="w-4 h-4 text-darkRed border-gray-300 bg-white">
    <label for="project_phase" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black">PRESEED</label>
  </div>

 <div class="flex items-center mb-2">
 <input id="project_phase" type="radio" value="SEED PHASE" name="project_phase" class="w-4 h-4 text-darkRed border-gray-300 bg-white">
    <label for="project_phase" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black">SEED PHASE</label>
 </div>

 <div class="flex items-center mb-2">
 <input id="project_phase" type="radio" value="ROUND A" name="project_phase" class="w-4 h-4 text-darkRed border-gray-300 bg-white">
    <label for="project_phase" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black">ROUND A</label>
 </div>

  <div class="flex items-center mb-2">
    <input id="project_phase" type="radio" value="SERIES B" name="project_phase" class="w-4 h-4 text-darkRed border-gray-300 bg-white">
    <label for="project_phase" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-black dark:text-black">SERIES B</label>
  </div>

    </div>
      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="block w-full px-5 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-darkRed rounded-lg">
        SUBMIT
      </button>
</form>

  </div>
</div>

      

  </body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\journeyController;
use App\Http\Controllers\GeneralFormController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

/*Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});*/

Route::get('/journey', 'App\Http\Controllers\journeyController@sniperj');

Route::get('/Aboutus', 'App\Http\Controllers\AboutusController@sniperA');

Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@sniperH');

Route::get('/getStarted', 'App\Http\Controllers\GeneralFormController@create');

Route::post('/store', 'App\Http\Controllers\GeneralFormController@store');

Route::get('/request', function () {
    return view('requestTable');
});

Route::get('/viewR', function () {
    return view('viewRequest');
});
```

Comment: Check the `laravel.log` file for errors.

Comment: You need to add a way to display validation errors  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors with the form.  The main one of which is not displaying validation errors.

Then you are requiring a field called `Adress` in the validation, but it is `Address` in the form name

Then you have an annoying mix of title and lowercase names, eg `email` and `Address` - be consistent (use lowercase)

Your `project_phase` input is repeated many times, but it is not indicated as an array by adding `[]` to every instance.

Fields that are arrays should be validated using * syntax, eg `'Services.*' => 'required',`, or if you just want to check that there is a services array, not to check each element, then:`'Services' => 'required',`

When working with form data, the very first thing I do is dump the request so that I can see exactly what I am dealing with, check the spelling of all the field names and that they contain the values I entered.

Only then will I proceed to validation.

Comment: I follow just what says also, I add the error message but nothing changes. It still not submitting the data. When I click on submit button it just refreshes the page.

Comment: because you don't display the errors.

Comment: at the top of the view page, write `dump($errors)` and see what it outputs after you submit the form